# Redirect everything to https except for certain directory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess I have the following condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which effectively redirects everything to https. But I want to make an exception for files (and subdirectories) in a certain directory. Namely: http://www.site.com/content/

Is this possible? What would that condition look like?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place before your condition listed above:

```
RewriteRule  ^content/  -  [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, placing it before the last rule resulted in a server error. But inserting it before the condition did the magic! It works!